# What is the limit of vector size to be used for SIMD operations with GNU C vector extensions?

Tags: c++, gcc, simd, avx

Is it possible to have a foo type:

```
typedef int foo __attribute__ ((vector_size (n)));
```

then expect it to be optimized for any length, like n=256 that is composed of four 512-bit vectors for Cascade Lake microarchitecture or eight 256-bit vectors for AVX-only CPU? Is it always guaranteed to be parallelized or vectorized if n is integer power of 2?

When it is accessed like `foo_var[i]=foo_var2[i]*2;` does it vectorize for any platform like amd, intel and arm, if vector length is 256 bytes or greater?

The GCC manual (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) mentions

> Only sizes that are positive power-of-two multiples of the base type size are currently allowed. [...]
>
> Specifying a combination that is not valid for the current architecture causes GCC to synthesize the instructions using a narrower mode.

But what actually happens: is it efficient?  And how wide a width is supported?

Comment: What is `__attribute__`? What is `vector_size`? Are you using language extensions? If so, you need to tell us what compiler you are using.

Comment: @eerorika: This is the GNU C vector extension, also supported by clang (and other compilers that support the GNU dialect of C).  But yes, this should be tagged [gcc].

Comment: Im using gcc but clang support would be good too. Thanks for the edit, you've read my mind and produced better text. It would be great if it could do 1024bit operation in two 512bit operations in avx512 cpu.

Comment: What happened when you actually tried it on https://godbolt.org/?  Easy enough to take a quick look at the asm for a very simple function that does one vector, or a very simple C loop using this vector size, for a couple different ISAs like x86-64 `-march=icelake-server` and ARM64 using `-mcpu=cortex-a53`.  And maybe ARM64 with SVE would be interesting.

Comment: Im away from computer and my smartphone dictionary killing the coding, especially in godbolt.

Comment: *It would be great if it could do 1024bit operation in two 512bit operations in avx512 cpu.* - Why would that be "great"?  Just so you can effectively unroll loops by using a wide type, or write future-proof code that will compile with a 1024-bit vector on some future CPU?

Comment: It would be great if it worked same for future cpus and todays cpus.(ie not doing catastrophic failures on vectorization)

Comment: Last time I checked, it looked like some clunky code-gen when it has to emulate a vector-width wider than the machine supports.  So it works, but not efficiently IIRC.  It's possible it was ok for simple cases, been a while since I looked.  And/or that some missed-optimization bugs have since been fixed.

Comment: Currently Im working on a cuda simulator that does same on simd and it has move-semantics problems with plain arrays. Plain array is not moved and it produces unnecessary mov instructions. Maybe because I did not implement rule of five yet, idk. I guess this vector can solve copy overhead problem as long as I stay within limits?